# Programming in Scala 2nd edition deprecated concepts

Tags: scala

I am reading *Programming in Scala 2nd edition* which is based on Scala 2.8

I have read on Scala release notes that many concepts like Actors that are explained in the above book have been phased out.

Can you suggest which chapters I can skip from that book and read from other sources?

Edit 1: I have checked the change log which gave me good idea of new features which have been added.

Any good resources for learning

- Akka Actors
- Parrallel collections
- Macros

Comment: Actors are still there, now part of the separate library called [Akka](http://akka.io/): *Starting with Scala 2.11.0, the Scala Actors library is deprecated. Already in Scala 2.10.0 the default actor library is Akka.* from [The Scala Actors Migration Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html). Seems the actor implementations aren't that different, so you can still gain knowledge from your book still.

Comment: Chapter 24, a part of it uses Manifest. Read reflection from docs and use TypeTag instead.

Comment: Notable additions: macros, value classes, improvements in collection. check change log http://www.scala-lang.org/download/changelog.html for lot more.